# Eclipse plug-in development: custom problem marker does not appear in Problems view

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am developing an Eclipse plug-in where I declare a custom problem marker. It has `org.eclipse.core.resources.problemmarker` as its super type, and the `persistent` attribute set to true. I contribute a custom `CategorizedProblem` class, where `getMarkerType` returns the id of my custom marker, that I add to the class with problems from the `reconcile` method in a custom `CompilationParticipant` using the `ReconcileContext.putProblems` method. The `CompilationParticipant` also declares the marker type under the `managedMarker` attribute:

**Relevant parts of plugin.xml:**

```
<extension
      point="org.eclipse.jdt.core.compilationParticipant">
   <compilationParticipant
         class="no.tobask.sb4e.FxControllerValidator"
         id="FxControllerValidator"
         createsProblems="true">
         <managedMarker
               markerType="no.tobask.sb4e.fxcontrollerproblemmarker">
         </managedMarker>
   </compilationParticipant>
</extension>
<extension
      id="no.tobask.sb4e.fxcontrollerproblemmarker"
      point="org.eclipse.core.resources.markers">
   <super
         type="org.eclipse.core.resources.problemmarker">
   </super>
   <persistent
         value="true">
   </persistent>
</extension>
```

**Relevant code from the CompilationParticipant:**

```
public void reconcile(ReconcileContext context) {
    ICompilationUnit clazz = context.getWorkingCopy();
    String className = clazz.findPrimaryType().getFullyQualifiedName();
    if (documentListener.isAssignedController(className)) {
        URL documentLocation = documentListener.getDocument(className);
        try {
            String fxmlContent = FXOMDocument.readContentFromURL(documentLocation);
            FXOMDocument document = new FXOMDocument(fxmlContent, documentLocation, Activator.getClassLoader(),
                    I18N.getBundle());
            CategorizedProblem[] problems = getProblems(context.getAST(AST.JLS11), document);
            if (problems != null) {
                context.putProblems("no.tobask.sb4e.fxcontrollerproblemmarker", problems);
            }
        } catch (IOException | JavaModelException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**The CategorizedProblem:**

```
public class FxControllerProblem extends CategorizedProblem {

    List<String> missingIds;
    IResource resource;

    public FxControllerProblem(List<String> missingIds, IResource resource) {
        this.missingIds = missingIds;
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getArguments() {
        return missingIds.toArray(new String[0]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getID() {
        return 1234;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return "One or more fx:ids from associated FXML document do not have corresponding fields";
    }

    @Override
    public char[] getOriginatingFileName() {
        return resource.getName().toCharArray();
    }

    @Override
    public int getSourceEnd() {
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSourceLineNumber() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSourceStart() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isError() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isWarning() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSourceEnd(int sourceEnd) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void setSourceLineNumber(int lineNumber) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void setSourceStart(int sourceStart) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public int getCategoryID() {
        return CAT_MEMBER;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMarkerType() {
        return "no.tobask.sb4e.fxcontrollerproblemmarker";
    }

}
```

The issue is that, while the warning does appear correctly in the Java editor, *it does not show up in the Problems view*.

Comment: Have you made sure, at some point, to set your Eclipse Application launcher to clear its configuration space?

Comment: First try going to project -> clean and clean all projects. Secondly if you are still having issues open your .ini file in eclipse install directory and add -clean param on the top. I suspect its a builder issue.